# Importing antlr4 Interval class into Python

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

I'm trying to compile a C like language to LLVM-ir with antlr4 and python3.
I want to keep the original source code as comments in LLVM. We can get the original text in Java as follows:

```
int a = ctx.start.getStartIndex();
int b = ctx.stop.getStopIndex();
Interval interval = new Interval(a,b);
input.getText(interval);
```

Which translated to Python becomes something like

```
a = ctx.start.getStartIndex();
b = ctx.stop.getStopIndex();
interval = Interval(a,b);
input.getText(interval);
```

But I can't find anywhere from where to import the Interval class into Python

```
from antlr4 import Interval
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cListenerExtended import extendedListener
  File "/mnt/c/Users/ebert/compilers/cListenerExtended.py", line 4, in <module>
    from antlr4 import TerminalNode, Interval
ImportError: cannot import name 'Interval'
```

Searching the internet has led to no avail, because the python documentation is rather sparse.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2 it's in the [IntervalSet](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/9f422d87b857835a01f56f60f80a131bd8cf2c63/runtime/Python2/src/antlr4/IntervalSet.py), but the Python 3 runtime doesn't seem to use the `Interval` class [any more](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/98dc2c0f0249a67b797b151da3adf4ffbc1fd6a1/runtime/Python3/src/antlr4/IntervalSet.py). Instead, it uses the builtin `range` structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to extract the original text from any context.

```py
def extract_original_text(self, ctx):
    token_source = ctx.start.getTokenSource()
    input_stream = token_source.inputStream
    start, stop  = ctx.start.start, ctx.stop.stop
    return input_stream.getText(start, stop)
```